# Glossaries: Addkey with acronyms

Tags: glossaries

I'm entirely new to Latex and currently trying to add a glossary to my thesis. I added a new key to access a glossaryentry via several grammatical forms (singular, plural and further german grammatical forms).

I add the keys like this:

```
\glsaddkey{alternative}{glsentrytext{\glslabel} defaultAlternativeValue}{\glsentryalternative}{\Glsentryalternative}{\glsalternativ}{\Glsalternative}{\GLSalternative}`

\glsaddkey{scndalternative}{glsentrytext{\glslabel} defaultAlternativeValue}{\glsentryscndalternative}{\Glsentryscndalternative}{\glsscndalternativ}{\Glsscndalternative}{\GLSscndalternative}
```

Add the Glossaryentry:

```
\newglossaryentry{htmlg}{
name=Hypertext Markup Language,
description={xxx},
alternative={HTML-Dokumenten}, %first key%
scndalternative={HTML-Dokuments} %second key%
}
\newglossaryentry{html}{
type=\acronymtype, 
name={HTML},
description={Hypertext Markup Language}, 
first={Hypertext Markup Language (HTML)\glsadd{htmlg}}, 
see=[Glossar:]{htmlg}}
```

And finally put it into the text:

```
... \Glsalternative{html} ... \Glsscndalternative{html} ...
```

After compiling, it looks like the following

```
Glsentrytexthtml defaultAlternativeValue
```

but it should show this:

```
...HTML-Dokumenten...HTML-Dokuments...
```

How can I use another key when I'd like to use an acronym?

The same method works perfectly without the additional key or without an acronym, the linking works with the additional key too.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Everything seems to work perfectly. (Though you probably meant to write `\glsentrytext` (note the backslash) and I am unsure of why you wrote `defaultAlternativeValue`.)

Comment: It should show the alternative/scndalternative value instead of "Glsentrytexthtml defaultAlternativeValue..."

Comment: But it does, doesn't it? You did not specify those keys for `html` (only for `htmlg`), so the default values are used, which is what you are getting. Or did you mean for `html` to be a sub-entry of `htmlg`? (This can be done with the `parent` key.) If you could post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that would help a lot in answering your question.